# How can I select a particular cell value in a grid view control?

Tags: gridview

How can I select a particular cell value in a grid view control to store in another variable (a string).

I created an empty row in my GridView and I entered blank values into that row.

How can I update the DB table from the GridView now?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in this.urgridname.Rows)
{
var a=row.Cells[1].Text
}
```

Gets a GridView row's cell value.

Answer (score 0):

***How can I select a particular cell value in a grid view control to store in another variable (a string).***

***How can I update the DB table from the GridView now?***

these are separate questions

***How can I select a particular cell value in a grid view control to store in another variable (a string).***

```
String value = myGridView.Rows(x).Cells(y).ToString()
```

***How can I update the DB table from the GridView now?***

if you are using a DataSet and have bound your GridView to a DataTable, you need to call the Update method on the TableAdapter for that DataTable:

```
myAdapter.Update(myDataSet.myDataTable)
```